# Textview's value reset when Fragment changed

Tags: android, textview, fragment

I have 3 fragment: [A], [B] and [C].
Fragment [A] have a textview , and a button that can change value of textview.

Stutation 1: textview with attribute: `android:textIsSelectable="true"`.
Stand on [A], change textview value from "Hello World" to "1", goto [C] and back to [A], textview's value is "1".
Image: [Stutation 1](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r47rju2b08n6pb8/F1.png)

Stutation 2: textview with attribute: `android:textIsSelectable="false"`.
Stand on [A], change textview value from "Hello World" to "1", goto [C] and back to [A], textview's value changed to default "Hello World".
Image: [Stutation 2](https://www.dropbox.com/s/mj2z6453e9oqdol/F2.png)

Can you tell me Why?
Is this a bug of framework?
Thank you very much!